# compressing validation tactics

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following validation code was handed to me and it just looks so repetative. How could I learn from his example on how to reduce the duplicate processes that occur for each input field that is being validated below....?  I want to be more efficient with JavaScript, not repeat the same functions over and over again just because a form adds on a new input element...

```
function isRequired(){
        firstNameRequired();
        lastNameRequired();
        stateRequired();
        gradYearRequired();
        relationshipRequired();
        birthdayRequired();
}

function firstNameRequired(){
        var firstName = document.forms['subscribeForm']['First Name'].value;
        if (firstName == null || firstName ==''){
        alert('Please enter your first name.');
            document.subscribeForm.elements['First Name'].style.backgroundColor='yellow';
            return false;
        }
    }

    function lastNameRequired(){
        var lastName = document.forms['subscribeForm']['Last Name'].value;
        if (lastName == null || lastName ==''){
                alert('Please enter your last name.');
            document.subscribeForm.elements['Last Name'].style.backgroundColor='yellow';
            return false;
        }
    }

    function stateRequired(){
        var state = document.forms['subscribeForm']['State'].value;
        if (state == null || state ==''){
                alert('Please enter your state of residence.');
            document.subscribeForm.elements['State'].style.backgroundColor='yellow';
            return false;
        }
    }

    function gradYearRequired(){
        var gradYear = document.forms['subscribeForm']['Graduation Year'].value;
        if (gradYear == null || gradYear ==''){
           alert('Please enter your graduation year.');
           document.subscribeForm.elements['Graduation Year'].style.backgroundColor='yellow';
           return false;
        }
    }

   function relationshipRequired(){
    var relationship = document.forms['subscribeForm']['ABC Link Relationship'].value;
    if(relationship == null || relationship == ''){
        alert('Please enter your relationship to ABC.');
        document.subscribeForm.elements['ABC Link Relationship'].style.backgroundColor='yellow';
        return false;
    }
   }

   function birthdayRequired(){
    var birthDay = document.forms['subscribeForm']['Birthdate'].value;
    if(birthDay == null || birthDay == ''){
        alert('Please enter your birthday.');
        document.subscribeForm.elements['Birthdate'].style.backgroundColor='yellow';
        return false;
    }
   }


...

<input type="submit" class="submitBtn" value="" onclick="isRequired()" />
```

Also, I have the flexibility to work in jQuery if need be.

Comment: Validation should be done server-side.

Comment: +1 Dude, I totally agree...I don't know why this company decided to leave this validation process on the front end. The funny thing, is that after the validation is successful, the form data goes back to their server anyway.  It just beats me why they handed us this form validation.  So just for the sake of getting this project off my chest, I just want to reduce some of the dup mess...at least for my sake... :) and just hand it off back to my PR.

Comment: I'd also like to recommend [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), although it's a sidetrack from your native JS example (it requires jQuery). It is quite versatile, easy to implement and is user-friendly - instead of displaying error messages as alerts (conundrum: what if a form has more than one error?), it displays error messages under each `<input>` element.

Answer (score 2):

Detect what parts in your code are repetitive and what parts do change from field to field. For example, you could create a function that takes two parameters: the field name and its label.

```
function validateRequiredField(name, label)
{
    var value = document.forms['subscribeForm'][name].value;
    if (value == null || value == '') {
        alert('Please enter your ' + label);
        document.forms['subscribeForm'][name].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can just call this function passing the name and the label as parameter:

```
validateRequiredField('First Name', 'first name');
validateRequiredField('ABC Link Relationship', 'relationship to ABC');
// ...
```

Keep in mind that these validations should be done also in server side, because someone can just disable JavaScript and send your form skipping your client side validation functions.

Comment: To cut down on typing even more, you could treat `label` as an optional param that uses the lower case version of `name` if it's not specified. `alert('Please enter your ' + (label || name.toLowerCase()))` - `validateRequiredField('First Name');`

Answer (score 1):

Because the only data being passed is the object and the alert message, instead of a whole custom function, use a single function with object and message params.

```
function isRequired(){
    required(document.forms['subscribeForm']['First Name'],'first name');
    required(document.forms['subscribeForm']['Last Name'],'last name');
    required(document.forms['subscribeForm']['State'],'state of residence');
    required(document.forms['subscribeForm']['Graduation Year'],'graduation year');
    required(document.forms['subscribeForm']['ABC Link Relationship'],'relationship to ABC');
    required(document.forms['subscribeForm']['Birthday'],'birthday');
}

function required(object,message){
    if (!obj) {
        alert('Please enter your '+message);
        obj.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the clean look and feel.  thank you I'll try it out and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend to use IDs to read out the form fields:

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" />
```

This allows you to use jQuery('#firstname') to select this input field.

Second, here's how I'd go about the task of making the code smaller:

What are you trying to do here?

1. You always read some value from the form (depending on an ID of sorts).
2. Then you check if that value is null.
3. If the value is not set you want to display an error message (depending on the ID again).
4. And you also want to mark the field that was missing and then return false.

So I'd code a function that does exactly that:

```
// function having a parameter for the ID and the custom error message
function checkFormField(fieldID, errorMsg) {

    // read value from field using jquery
    value = $(fieldID).value();

    // check for null or empty
    if (value == null || value == '') {

        // display custom error message
        alert(errorMsg);

        // change color of field using jQuery
        $(fieldID).css('background', 'yellow');

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you can reuse this function for every field you want to check. The new isRequired method would look like this:

```
function isRequired(){
    checkFormField('#firstname', 'Please enter your first name.');
    checkFormField('#lastname', 'Please enter your last name.');
    // and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this example would require name attributes that can be used as identifiers (no spaces)

```
<input name="first_name" type="text" />
<input name="last_name" type="text" />
```

js:

```
function validateRequired(slug, field){
    // test for passing condition
    if (field.value !== null && field.value !== '') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert('Please enter your ' + field.str);
    }
    return false;
}

/**
* Validate a form using a ruleset object
* 
*/
function validateFields(ruleset, form){
    var field = {};
    var errors = 0;

    // Loop though the ruleset
    for(var index in ruleset) { 
        // 
        if (ruleset.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
            field = ruleset[index];
            // check if input exists
            if (form[index]){
                field.value = form[index].value
            }
            if (ruleset[index].required) {
                if (!validateRequired(field)){
                    errors++;
                    field.invalid = true;
                }
            }
            // you could add more rules here...
        }
    }   
    return errors === 0;
}

var valid = validateFields({
    first_name : {
        required : true,
        str: 'first name'
    },
    last_name : {
        required : true,
        str: 'last name'
    }
    // ...
}, document.forms['subscribeForm']);
```